# Fetch concurrent tables with Criteria API

Tags: java, criteria-api

I've got 3 entity classes:
(The `BaseAutoIncrementModel` contains the declaration of the id for each entity)

**Table 1: Dossier**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DOSSIER", schema = "ADOP")
public class Dossier extends BaseAutoIncrementModel<Integer> implements BaseModelCode<Integer> {
...
}
```

**Table 2: AlerteDossier**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALERTE_DOSSIER", schema = "ADOP")
public class AlerteDossier extends BaseAutoIncrementModel<Integer> implements BaseModelCode<Integer> {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_DOSSIER")
    private Dossier dossier;

    ...
}
```

**Table 3: AlerteEnvoi**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALERTE_ENVOI", schema = "ADOP")
public class AlerteEnvoi extends BaseAutoIncrementModel<Integer> implements BaseModelCode<Integer> {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ALERTE_DOSSIER")
    private AlerteDossier alerteDossier;

    ...
}
```

**What I have atm:**

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<AlerteEnvoi> query = builder.createQuery(AlerteEnvoi.class);
Root<AlerteEnvoi> root = query.from(AlerteEnvoi.class);
query.select(root);
List<Predicate> predicateList = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

As you can see in `AlerteEnvoi` the `AlerteDossier` table is eagerly loaded, though in `AlerteDossier` the `Dossier` table is lazily loaded.

I need to create, using the Criteria Api, a select statement for `AlerteEnvoi` where `Dossier` would also be loaded within the `AlerteDossier` entity.
I know how I'd need to fetch the `AlerteDossier` within the `AlerteEnvoi` if `AlerteDossier` would be lazily-loaded (`root.fetch("alerteDossier", JoinType.LEFT`), I've got no clue how to fetch a sub-entity of a sub-entity though. Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it out yet, but heard from a collegue something like this should be do-able:

```
Fetch<AlerteEnvoi, AlerteDossier> fetchAlerteDossier = root.fetch("alerteDossier", JoinType.LEFT);
fetchAlerteDossier.fetch("dossier", JoinType.LEFT);
```

I'll be putting this answer as accepted once I've tested it out.